# Chromium video autoplay not working (ignores autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required parameter)

Tags: html5-video, chromium, autostart, kiosk

We have a kiosk system (running on ubuntu) which used chromium 65 until now.
We want to update to the newest version (90), but as soon we update the autoplay don't work as before.
I could figure out that the autoplay behavior has changed (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). I searched for a way to reenable the autoplay (with sound!), i found the parameter "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required" which should reenable the autoplay.
Unfortunaly this is not the case, i still have to start the video myself. We also have (sometimes) a few weired behaviors, sometimes the sound is played but the video not. Sometimes i cant even start the Video.

Currently installed:

- chromium-browser 90.0.4430.93-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra 90.0.4430.93-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

For testing purposes i used the following simple html (i also tried it without the source tag).

```
<video autoplay>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="preview.mp4" >
</video>
```

I hope somebody can help with that and maybe have a explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience somewhere between version 70 and 80 the --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required parameter stopped working.

Whether autoplay is allowed is now determined by magic.
It is said you need to (manually) play at least 7 seconds of video (with audio) After doing that about 20 times Googles Media Engagement Index database will have learned you want to allow autoplay for that site.

But mind you, playing videos shorter might get your site disqualified again.
This is very annoying as aborting videos too soon, like you do during development, gets you further away from autoplay.

You can see your current stats in chrome://media-engagement

But these stats are unreliable. I have projects on origins which qualify, but still refuse to autoplay and project which do not qualify, but do autoplay.
A guest session is said to start with a fresh index, but I have never seen this make a difference.

Google has exempted its own youtube.com from this indexing. Youtube can always autoplay. Maybe you can find a way to get your own domains in that list too.

You can build a check to see whether the autoplay was prevented using a promise which is rejected with a message explaining you autoplay was rejected because the user didn't interact with the page first. There are other reasons too, so do check the error message.